# does oracle hard parse whenever the text changes

Tags: oracle, performance, parsing

My understanding of hard parse in Oracle is, when a SQL statement is processed, if no matching text is found it will be hard parsed. I am working on an assignment, where
they fire multiple SQL's from a service as below(around 50 variations executed multiple times)

```
select * from emp where emp_no in (:V1,:V2);
select * from emp where emp_no in (:V1,:V2,:V3);
select * from emp where emp_no in (:V1,:V2,V3,:V4);
```

This in turn generates multiple SQL_ID's with same PHV. My question is, does this create hard parse of each statement? Reason is

1. AWR report shows that only .10 seconds of total elapsed time of SQL is hard parsed time
2. V$SQL/v$SQLSTAS shows only a fraction of elapsed time is hard parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

When you submit a statement to the database, it hashes the text to produce a SQL_id. Meaning you have a cursor for each => there must have been a hard parse.

You can verify this by querying `v$sql`. This will have an entry for each version. You can also see the number of hard parses by checking the `parse count (hard)` stat:

```
var v1 number;
var v2 number;
var v3 number;

alter system flush shared_pool;

select sql_id, executions
from   v$sql
where  sql_text like 'select * from hr.employees%';

no rows selected

select n.display_name, s.value
from   v$mystat s
join   v$statname n
on     s.statistic# = n.statistic#
where  n.name like 'parse count%';

DISPLAY_NAME                 VALUE   
parse count (total)           1682 
parse count (hard)             449 
parse count (failures)           4 
parse count (describe)           0 

select * from hr.employees 
where  employee_id in ( :v1 );
select * from hr.employees 
where  employee_id in ( :v1, :v2 );
select * from hr.employees 
where  employee_id in ( :v1, :v2, :v3 );


select sql_id, executions
from   v$sql
where  sql_text like 'select * from hr.employees%';

SQL_ID              EXECUTIONS   
63dqkasu1w4du                1 
4kr9jqam2p6dw                1 
8gbwr8cry9d84                1 

select n.display_name, s.value
from   v$mystat s
join   v$statname n
on     s.statistic# = n.statistic#
where  n.name like 'parse count%';

DISPLAY_NAME                 VALUE   
parse count (total)           1697 
parse count (hard)             457 
parse count (failures)           4 
parse count (describe)           0
```

So what happens if we run the statements again?

Let's see:

```
select * from hr.employees 
where  employee_id in ( :v1 );
select * from hr.employees 
where  employee_id in ( :v1, :v2 );
select * from hr.employees 
where  employee_id in ( :v1, :v2, :v3 );

select sql_id, executions
from   v$sql
where  sql_text like 'select * from hr.employees%';

SQL_ID              EXECUTIONS   
63dqkasu1w4du                2 
4kr9jqam2p6dw                2 
8gbwr8cry9d84                2 

select n.display_name, s.value
from   v$mystat s
join   v$statname n
on     s.statistic# = n.statistic#
where  n.name like 'parse count%';

DISPLAY_NAME                 VALUE   
parse count (total)           1707 
parse count (hard)             457 
parse count (failures)           4 
parse count (describe)           0
```

So:

- The execution count for each SQL_id increased by 1
- The count of hard parses stayed the same (457)

=> no new hard parses!

This goes part of the way to explaining why you are seeing such small values for hard parsing in AWR etc. Hopefully you're parsing each variation once, then executing it *many*, **many** times.

Also, while *relatively* expensive and something to avoid, hard parsing is still fast in absolute terms. Particularly for simple statements such as the above.